# C# MVC - How to display records from SQL with intended line breaks

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a new application in C# MVC and have ran into an issue when displaying data from my table onto the webpage. I can successfully display the data from my table onto a webpage with no errors however one of my columns in my table can have multiple pieces of information. For Example;

```
Column Example Data = "Information 1; information 2; information 3;"
```

This successfully displays to a html table in my view however I would like to take a new line after each `";"`. I have tried to wrap this in HTML and store it in my SQL but this still doesn't work. Instead the tag is just printed as text on the page.

If anyone would know how to go about this, it would be appreciated.

Comment: first put code to show how are you displaying the information. then we can give improvements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think before rendering that date you should use
yourcontent.replace(";", Environment.NewLine);

and return new IHTMLString(yourcontent) or use HTML.Raw(yourcontent)

This is pseudo code, just so you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks very much. This is exactly what I was looking for. Worked perfectively.